# mongo timeseries with node, no moongose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this collection defined

```
db.createCollection(
  "raw_data",
  {
    timeseries: {
        timeField: "timestamp",
        metaField: "metadata"
    }
  }
)
```

when sending data to using 'mongodb' client I'm sending

```
{
  device_uid: 'ht',
  metadata: { type: 'h&t' },
  timestamp: 1710859285918,
  measure: { status: 'off' }
}
```

I got this error

> MongoServerError: 'timestamp' must be present and contain a valid BSON UTC datetime value

What I'm doing wrong?

I already tried also to send

```
{
  device_uid: 'ht',
  metadata: { type: 'h&t' },
  timestamp: '2024-03-19T14:46:26.040Z',
  measure: {
    temperature_celsius: 12.380277178155694,
    humidity_perce: 74.98333906368329
  }
}
```

But same error

also tried

```
{
  metadata: { device_uid: 'ht' },
  timestamp: 'ISODate("2024-03-19T14:53:56.274Z")',
  measure: { status: 'on' }
}
```

same error

Comment: For the last version (i.e. the one with `ISODate`), can you try not to wrap it in quotes so it is not a string?

Comment: not working also if using quotes. Please, read my own answer. Just as much fun as much the solution is simple. Stupid problem, stupid solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that I can use

```
timestamp: new Date()
```

and all is working